# Angular HTML markup in scope

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Maybe is a stupid question but I'm really new with Angular and trying to pick up some knowledges. So I have a scope which I get via API ($http) and after conversion is a html markup

```
<li>some list</li>
```

and I would like to project this one in DOM, trying

`<ul>{{myscopevariable}}</ul>`

but I get just the raw text

with php would be like `<ul><?= myscopevariable ?></ul>`

Comment: When modifying the DOM using angular you generally use directives.  If you just want to include some snippet of HTML you can use ng-bind-html (need to include angular-sanitize.js and "ngSanitize" dependency) on an element, another directive that may be helpful is ng-include.  Alternatively if none of the existing directives achieve the goal you can write your own.  I'll see if I can throw together an answer here.  Check out egghead.io and YouTube AngularJS Best Practices videos for some ramp up info.

Comment: Thank u for this nice advice I will check my dependencies. An example would be really appreciated as well. Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JS

```
angular.module("myApp", ["ngSanitize"]).controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
  $scope.someHTML = "<li>just testing</li>";
})
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.14" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.14" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <ul ng-bind-html="someHTML">
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/e1zoOrEVwqdIDPujMpPC?p=preview

Comment: I think i'm going to love angular!

Comment: fefe indeed have to admit I've become quite a fan boy and I generally don't like them :)  I still am not a huge fan of JS but the framework makes it far more appealing to me.  Just FYI as well generally speaking it's frowned upon to do DOM manipulation in your controller since it then means you can't test the controller independent of the view (it becomes coupled) so try to avoid it and use directives if you need to do DOM manipulation.

Comment: okay I will try to pick up some more info is starting to be interesting

Comment: one thing can I ask regarding to this?

Comment: Sure shoot conversations in SO are frowned upon as well but if it's pertinent to the question it's fine, if not post another question.

Comment: I have the list what actually contains hyperlinks and dropdowns part of a bootstrap navbar but none of the links are usable. The dropdown won't fire so actually DOM manipulation on flow in this case doesn't work. What would be in this case a workaround?

Comment: Would be better if you actually post this as a separate question and include a plnkr.co or jsfiddle showing the issue in action feel free to link here if you'd like me to check it out further but not sure just based on the description here.

Comment: @shaunhusain - nice clean markup and great simple plunker to get my SPA running

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ng-bind-html` directive (Documentation [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)). Prior to 1.2 there also existed `ng-bind-html-unsafe`.

In your example:

```
<ul>some list</list>
  <li ng-bind-html='myscopevariable'></li>
  ....
</ul>
```

You have to include the `ngSanitize` module to have it work (e.g. `<script  src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/angular-sanitize.js"></script>` in Header and `var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngSanitize']);`)

See this [plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/kaGsaKgHBzDquqJEe1CS?p=preview) for some working code.